# Database of survey information

Tags: sql, mysql

How does this look?  It has been over a year since my database concepts class and I have never worked with MySQL.  I have chosen InnoDB as my engine because of foreign key support using UTF-8 based on advice from an [earlier review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14619/mysql-database-design-review).  Everything works as it should when deleting and updating, but I am worried I am doing something that may be considered bad practice.

The main table `Tracker` manages different survey name and descriptions.  The table `Card` holds information on each person who has been surveyed.  `Survey` holds the results of each `Card` response for the survey being tracked by `Tracker` and has a unique composite key.

If a `cardID` is deleted or updated the corresponding composite key of `Survey` will be deleted or updated.  If  a `trackID` is deleted or updated this will delete or update the corresponding `cardID` fields in `Card`.

**ERD design image:**

[image]

Is this the right way to apply a composite key in this way? Are there any changes that should be made? Are there any suggestions for changes?

```
CREATE TABLE `Tracker` (
 `trackID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tName` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tDesc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`trackID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `Card` (
 `cardID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `trackID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fName` varchar(21) NOT NULL,
 `mName` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lName` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `isMember` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cardID`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`trackID`) REFERENCES `Tracker`(`trackID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `Survey` (
 `cardID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `trackID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `q0` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `q1` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `q2` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `q3` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `q4` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `q5` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cardID`, `trackID`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`trackID`) REFERENCES `Tracker`(`trackID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (`cardID`) REFERENCES `Card`(`cardID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with *Corbin* and *Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams*, and here are some other notes:

> The main table `Tracker` manages different survey name and descriptions.

Then, I'd call it `Survey` with attributes `surveyId`, `name` and `description`.

> The table `Card` holds information on each person who has been surveyed.

Then, I'd call it `SurveyedPerson` with attributes `surveryPersonId` etc.

> `Survey` holds the results of each `Card` response for the survey being tracked by `Tracker` and has a unique composite key.

Then, `SurveyResult` (or `Answer`) holds the results of each `SurveyPerson` response for the `Survey` (being tracked by `Survey.surveyId`) and has a unique composite key.

In your first question I did not understand the purpose of these tables (see my comment on your first question). I don't know whether your original names are special terms in the field of the survey science or anything but the names above seem easier to understand, read and therefore maintain (for me, at least).

---

1. Are you sure that you need the `Card.trackId` attribute? It seems duplication of `Survey.trackId` (so it's redundant).
2. Are you sure that you don't need to store multiple `Survey`s (answers) for the same `Card` (person)? What happens when the same person answers to multiple surveys? Do you duplicate their name?
3. Attribute lengths in the `Card` table seems too short. You might have problems with [the new name of this guy](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/somerset/7707098.stm). AFAIK [email addresses also could be 254 characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address).

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick thing:  `int(1)` probably does not mean what you think it means.

```
mysql> create table int_length (x int(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO int_length VALUES (1234);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT x FROM int_length;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 1234 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`int(x)` is basically used for zerofill and nothing else.  If you want a smaller data type, you'll need to use a small data type (`tinyint`, etc).  (Note that this doesn't apply to `var` types.  `varchar(5)` is `<= 5` characters, and varchar(10) is `<= 10` characters.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider normalizing `Survey` further, in that having many fields with only a differing numeric suffix indicates that it should be a single field with another key.

```
CREATE TABLE `Survey` (
 `cardID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `trackID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `questionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `response` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cardID`, `trackID`, `questionID`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`trackID`) REFERENCES `Tracker`(`trackID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (`cardID`) REFERENCES `Card`(`cardID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (`questionID`) REFERENCES `Question`(`questionID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```